# Notepad++ Fill every x Space with a Character in a Single Line

Tags: notepad++

Basically I want to take this: Augustus Sepurcius Bibulus Spurius Calavius Taurinus Titus Nigilius Celatus
and turn it into this: "Augustus Sepurcius Bibulus" "Spurius Calavius Taurinus" "Titus Nigilius Celatus"

I'm trying to add a (ton) of generated Roman names to a game I'm playing and I have to enclose each name in quotations to get a longer name free of underscores or hyphens, and adding in each quotation would take a ridiculous amount of time and require patience I don't have.

I'm a super-huge notepad++, coding, programming, etc. noob so any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to enclose groups of 3 names in quotes. You can match the three names in a group then replace with the quoted match. Make sure *Regular expression* is checked in your replace window and replace (*Replace All*):

```
(\w+ \w+ \w+)
```

with:

```
"$1"
```

`$1` is a reference to the first (and in this case unique) matched group.

Comment: You're a GOD! Could I ask how I would do this exact same thing except with a group of 2? I tried fiddling with it myself but to no avail. I'm such a pleb lol.

Comment: I got it after fiddling with it some more! `(\w+ \w+)`